# Is it possible to use the nrf native_posix board on windows?

Tags: windows, zephyr-rtos, unity-test-framework

I have a project built for an nrf board. The project uses zephyr os. Right now we're developing on windows. We'd like to add unit testing with unity/cmock. I've been looking in to the nrf documents https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/app_dev/testing_unity_cmock/index.html  and finding some examples (like this https://github.com/antmicro/zephyr-cmock-unity-module) but they all use the native_posix board. As far as I understand that wouldn't be possible to use on Windows, is that correct? Do I have any other options for unity + nrf + zphyr + windows, or do I need to make a linux vm to run unit tests from?

Comment: You might have a few options though I am unfamiliar with this module specifically. First is to run every in WSL, so that's basically an tightly integrated Linux VM. Alternatively, these tests might work from a qemu target instead of the `native_posix` one which might have a native windows version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WSL in windows. If you already have the Nordic SDK (which includes a downstream version of zephyr) then you just need to point to Zephyr OS in WSL. You also need to install the Toolchain for linux by following the instructions from here

https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/latest/nrf/installation/installing.html